# str_replace not working correctly

Tags: php

Why not give the correct exit code?

My full code:

```
<?php

$numA_m = "2";
$res = '["110","2","1"]';
$numA_s = json_decode($res);
if ($numA_m == 1) {
    $A_num_s = array("1", "2", "3", "4","110");
    $A_nam_s = array("egh", "guide", "irl", "tic", "all");
}
if ($numA_m == 2) {
    $A_num_s = array("1", "2","110");
    $A_nam_s = array("sub", "forg","all");
}
$Rsp = str_replace($A_num_s, $A_nam_s, $numA_s);
$Rsp_In = str_replace($A_nam_s, $A_num_s, $Rsp);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Rsp);

echo '<p>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Rsp_In);
?>
```

The output should be:

> Array (
> [0] => all
> [1] => forg
> [2] => sub
> )
>
> Array (
> [0] => 110
> [1] => 2
> [2] => 1 
> )

But it is like this:

> Array
>  (
> [0] => subsub0
> [1] => forg
> [2] => sub
>  )
>  Array
>  (
> [0] => 110
> [1] => 2
> [2] => 1
>  )

What do i do?

**DEMO:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/srj-k3d

Comment: Well this is extremely confusing and hard to read, but the reason you end up with `subsub0` is because you're replacing every instance of `1` with `sub` in the string `110`, hence `subsub0`.

Comment: Taylor: people trying to help you, if you found the answer, then accept it (on each answer, left-side - click accept)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This outputs the desired result

```
$numA_m = "2";
$res = '["110","2","1"]';
$numA_s = json_decode($res);
if ($numA_m == 1) {
    $A_num_s = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "110");
    $A_nam_s = array("egh", "guide", "irl", "tic", "all");
}
if ($numA_m == 2) {
    $A_num_s = array("110", "2", "1"); // changed order
    $A_nam_s = array("all", "forg", "sub");
}
$count = 1;
$Rsp = str_replace($A_num_s, $A_nam_s, $numA_s, $count);
$Rsp_In = str_replace($A_nam_s, $A_num_s, $Rsp, $count);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Rsp);

echo '<p>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Rsp_In);
```

**Explanation:**

str_replace searches for the strings in the order you send them. So, if in your case you are searching for `1` and then `110`, it will replace **all occurrences** of `1` before reaching the `110`.

If you replace the `110` first, it will be replaced as expected.

Comment: If i change `$numA_m` of `2` to `1` it don't work. see: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/srj-k3d

Comment: Read my explanation and you will understand why it has this behavior

Answer (score 0):

First, `str_replace` works correct.
What you can do is replace the order in your array:

```
$A_num_s = array("110", "1", "2");
$A_nam_s = array("all", "sub", "forg");
```

In your version str_replace sees "110" as two 1's (and a 0) and replaces both with "sub" ("subsub0").

With the changed order "110" will be matched first, cause `str_replace` searches for your pattern (`$A_num_s`) in the order you provided it.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` replaces in order, checking the entire subject of replacement against each replacement value in order, for example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
// Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

So, all you need to do is replace 110, before 1, otherwise the 1's in 110 get replaced first:

`$A_num_s = array("110", "2", "1");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [array_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) like that:
Bit more difficult to understand perhaps, but works ;)

```
$numA_m = "2";
$res = '["110","2","1"]';
$numA_s = json_decode($res);
if ($numA_m == 1) {
    $A_num_s = array("1", "2", "3", "4","110");
    $A_nam_s = array("egh", "guide", "irl", "tic", "all");
}
if ($numA_m == 2) {
    $A_num_s = array("1", "2","110");
    $A_nam_s = array("sub", "forg","all");
}

$Rsp = array_replace($numA_s, $A_num_s, array_reverse($A_nam_s));
$Rsp_In = array_replace($Rsp, $A_nam_s, array_reverse($A_num_s));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Rsp);


echo '<p>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Rsp_In);
?>
```